# round to the nearest tenth

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

Please how to round to the nearest decimal tenth?
Example : 0.56 => 0.5; 2.78 => 2.8

Comment: You can use `num.toFixed(1)`, although why does `0.56` get rounded to `0.5`?

Comment: No, output is 0.6

Comment: It says `0.56 = > 0.5` in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by 10, then round then divide back by 10:

```js
const round = (num) => Math.round(num * 10)/10

console.log(round(0.56))
console.log(round(2.78))
```

Then using the same logic, you can write a general rounding function:

```js
const round = (num, decimal) => Math.round(num * 10**decimal)/10**decimal

console.log(round(5.142533564, 4))
console.log(round(62.5236, 2))
```

Comment: Input => 0.56   ;  Output => 0.5

Comment: 0.56 rounds up to 0.6. If you want it to only round down, replace `Math.round()` in my solution with  `Math.floor()`